# Is it possible to collapse a css grid column if the contents are empty

Tags: html, css

I have a component with an OK/Cancel button, where I want the buttons both the same width regardless of the text size (eg different cultures)

So, a simplified mockup which is close to what I have is...

```
<div id="container">
  <div class="button">OK</div>
  <div class="button">Cancel</div>
</div>

#container {
  background: green;  
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr minmax(0, 1fr)
}

.button {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
  min-width: 40px;
  width: auto;
  margin: 5px;
  background: yellow;
}
```

Can also see [at this codepen](https://codepen.io/peterjc/pen/MWGvgEe)

So, we can see if the OK text is long, then the Cancel button also grows to the same width

[image]

However, the component I am using (3rd party) also used the OK for just close

eg

```
<div id="container">
  <div class="button">Close</div>  
</div>
```

and now I have an unwanted gap on the right hand side

[image]

I can target the component classes, but not the structure.

So, is there any way via just CSS I can have this grid to act like a `grid-template-columns: 1fr 0` if the second div is not there?

Comment: does `grid-template-columns: 1fr auto` fills your needs ? or `.button:only-child {
  grid-column:span 2
}`

Comment: The first one does not have the second button grow in width with longer text, however .button:only-child {
  grid-column:span 2
} seems to do the trick!

Comment: oki, i'll drop an answer if that is it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may check if the span is the `:only-child` and make it span both columns

```css
#container {
  background: green;
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr minmax(0, 1fr)
}

.button {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
  min-width: 40px;
  width: auto;
  margin: 5px;
  background: yellow;
}

.button:only-child {
  grid-column: span 2;
}
```

```html
<p>Test :only-child</p>
<div id="container">
  <div class="button">Close</div>
</div>
```

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:only-child

Answer (score 0):

You can use the 'auto' value like this:

```
#container {
 background: green;  
 right: 0;
 position: absolute;
 display: grid;
 grid-template-columns: auto minmax(0, 1fr)
}
```

you can find more info here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-auto-columns

Comment: Thanks for that, but unfortunately the second button will then not grow in width if the first does have long text.